# How access SFTP with user/password using git ftp?

Tags: git, authentication, ftp, sftp, git-ftp

I want to access SFTP server with user/password using git ftp and it doesn't work.

> git ftp push -vv

```
lun. 07 sept. 2020 14:08:31 CEST: Syncroot is './'.
lun. 07 sept. 2020 14:08:31 CEST: Host is 'myhost:port'.
lun. 07 sept. 2020 14:08:31 CEST: User is 'user'.
lun. 07 sept. 2020 14:08:31 CEST: Password is set.
lun. 07 sept. 2020 14:08:31 CEST: CACert is ''.
lun. 07 sept. 2020 14:08:31 CEST: Insecure is '0'.
lun. 07 sept. 2020 14:08:31 CEST: Proxy is ''.
lun. 07 sept. 2020 14:08:31 CEST: Path is ''.
lun. 07 sept. 2020 14:08:31 CEST: The remote sha1 is saved in file '.git-ftp.log'.
lun. 07 sept. 2020 14:08:31 CEST: Check if curl is functional.
lun. 07 sept. 2020 14:08:31 CEST: Retrieving last commit from sftp://user:***@myhost:port/.
*   Trying myhost:port...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to myhost (myhost) port port (#0)
#=#=-  #       #                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               * User: user
* Known hosts: /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts
#=O=#     #        #                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           * Authentication using SSH public key file
-#O=- #      #          #                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      -=O#-   #        #           #                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 * Authentication failure
-=O=-#      #         #           #                                                                                                                                                                                                                            -=O=-  #       #          #             #                                                                                                                                                                                                                      * Closing connection 0
curl: (67) Authentication failure
```

It seems like git ftp try connect with ssh key but i want to use basic authentication (user/password).

How to do ?

Thanks !

Comment: Try something from here: https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp/issues/309

Comment: Thank you for your awnser.
I have tried using curl with the option "-o PreferredAuthentications=password" but I get the same result : Athentication failure.
It still trying to connect with an ssh key.